# Contractible four-manifold which admits a decomposition

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, 4-manifolds

Let $M^4$ be a noncompact, contractible, smooth manifold. Suppose there exists an exhaustion $M=\bigcup_{i\ge 1} U_i$ by open sets such that (1) $\bar U_i \subset U_{i+1}$ and (2) each $U_i$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2 \times S^2$. Can we prove that $M$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^4$?

Comment: This seems pretty likely; you need to show that M is simply connected at infinity. Since M is contractible, it should have vanishing $H_1$ at infinity; the hypothesis says that there are copies of $S^1 \times S^2$ far out at infinity so commutators would be trivial. But that's just a heuristic argument.